# If $f_n \to f$ pointwise and $|f_n(x)| \leq C$ for $n$ large enough, does Dominated Convergence Theorem still work?

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Let $f_n \to f$ pointwise a.e., and for a.e. $x$, we know $|f_n(x)| \leq C$ as long as $n$ is large enough (so if $n \geq N$ where $N$ may depend on $x$).

If we are integrating over a compact domain, does the dominate convergences theorem still apply and we get $\int f_n \to \int f$?

Comment: The constant function $C$ is integrable on a set of finite measure; if your compact domain has finite measure (as compact sets in $\mathbb{R}$ w.r.t the Lebesgue measure always do), then the constant function $C$ is integrable.

Comment: @user25959: Caution!  Note that $N$ may depend on $x$, so $C$ does not dominate $f_n$.

Comment: Thanks, didn't read it carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, this is not true.

Work on the interval $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure, and let $f_n = n 1_{(0, 1/n)}$.  Then $f_n(x) \to 0$ pointwise (everywhere), so we take $f=0$.  Moreover, if we take $C = 0$, then for each $x$ we have $|f_n(x)| \le C$ as soon as $n \ge 1/x$ (this is our $N$, which we are allowing to depend on $x$).  But $\int f_n = 1$ for every $n$ while $\int f = 0$.

If you instead took $f_n = n^2 1_{(0,1/n)}$ you could satisfy the hypotheses and have $\int f_n \to \infty$.

Your assumptions are equivalent to "suppose $f_n \to f$ pointwise a.e. where $f$ is a bounded function".  Generally, you can't get pointwise convergence to imply convergence of integrals, unless you have rather good control over the functions $f_n$ themselves; control over the limiting function $f$ is not enough.

If there is a fixed $N$ that works for every $x$, then the conclusion will hold: we have, for every $n \ge N$ and almost every $x$, $|f_n(x)| \le C$.  Assuming your "compact domain" has finite measure (which it will if you are using Lebesgue measure) then the constant function $C$ is integrable, so you can apply the dominated convergence theorem to the sequence $f_N, f_{N+1}, \dots$.